# Cforest Regression: Error in ctree_control(alpha = 0.02) : unused argument (alpha = 0.02)

Tags: r, random-forest

I'm doing a cforest regression, which works without specified controls. Here is my code:

```
Test1 = cforest(X.OfPrevious ~ State + X.Change1YrSoy + X.Change2YrSoy + X.Change1YrCorn + 
  X.Change2YrCorn +X.Change1YrW  + X.Change2YrW + X.Change1YrCotton + X.Change2YrCotton + 
  FebWASDECO.USoy+FebWASDECO.UCorn+FebWASDECO.UWheat +FebWASDECO.UCotton +NovWASDECO.USoy + 
  NovWASDECO.UCorn + NovWASDECO.UWheat + NovWASDECO.Ucotton + DecSoyCornRatio +
  JanSoyCornRatio+DecSoyWheatRatio+JanSoyWheatRatio+DecSoyCottonRatio+
  JanSoyCottonRatio, trainme1, control = ctree_control(alpha = 0.02))
```

Without the part `control = ctree_control(alpha = 0.02)` the cforest works fine.
 However, once I try to tighten the controls from the default alpha of 0.05 I get the error

> "Error in ctree_control(alpha = 0.02) : unused argument (alpha =
>   0.02)"

Please help me lol

Comment: Please, try the following command: `library(partykit); cf <- cforest(dist ~ speed, data = cars, control=ctree_control(alpha=0.02))`. Do you get the same error message ?
`

Comment: AWESOME - thanks! I didn't know I had to have both partykit AND party installed - case closed brotha